# Optimize file reader and plotting script using Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've written the code below to import a number of files from a folder, read and convert them before plotting them in a 3D plot. The number of files is usually larger than 30 and lower than 200 but exceptions might occur. Each file has arround 5000 lines with 3 plottable values. It works and produces a nice 3D plot, but it is very slow. I suspect I have made an array or list grow inside itself. I am particularly suspecting the third for loop. I've tried to run it using 121 files and takes about half an hour to plot.

Each data file is a diffractogram and what I want to do is essentially something like this:
http://www.carbonhagen.com/_/rsrc/1404718703333/abstracts/insitux-raydiffractionsynthesisofgrapheneoxideandreducedgrapheneoxide/M%C3%B8ller%20Storm%20res%20pic.png?height=371&width=522

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import glob
import os

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'C:\Users\mkch\Python_Scripts\znox_1','*.ras'))

sourcefiles = []

for file_path in file_list:     #this forloops reads all files 
with open(file_path) as f_input:
    sourcefiles.append(f_input.readlines())
```

Now all the files have been imported into the list `sourcefiles`.

```
data = []
alldata = []
cutdata = []
length = 118#len(sourcefiles)
for i in range(0,length):
    l = len(sourcefiles[i])
    cdata = sourcefiles[i][320:l-2] 
    cutdata.append(cdata)
```

This for loop removes headliners and the last two lines in each file.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

verts = []
zs =  list(range(length))
print zs                                       

for j in range(length):
lines = cutdata[j][:]
x = []
y = []
z = []
for line in lines:
    a, b, c = line.split()[0:3]
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)   
y[0], y[-1] = 0, 0        
verts.append(list(zip(x, y)))
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=['r', 'g', 'b','y']) 
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')
```

This bit of code splits each line into the three values that needs plotting. Then it adds the the data to a plot. I suspect the above code is taking quite long.

```
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 100)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 120)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 120000)

plt.xlabel('2$ \theta$')    
plt.show()
```

Standard plotting things.